# How to Get Node Text of treeView on the click event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I want to Get the Text of the node in the treeview. I am using the `click()` event.. When I am using the `AfterSelect()` event I can get the node text by `e.Node.text` . how can I get the text by using `Click()` event

Answer (score 12):

I don't recommend using the `Click` event for this. The reason is that there are a *lot* of different places that the user could click on a TreeView control, and many of them do not correspond to an actual node. The `AfterSelect` event is a much better choice—it was designed for this usage.

Beyond that, the `Click` event is rather difficult to use, because it doesn't provide you very much information in the handler method. It doesn't tell you which button was clicked, where the click event occurred, etc. You have to retrieve all of this information manually. It's recommended that you subscribe to either the `MouseClick` or the `MouseDown`/`MouseUp` event instead.

To figure out what the user clicked on, you need to use the [`TreeView.HitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5thyy89.aspx) method, which returns a [`TreeViewHitTestInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewhittestinfo.aspx) object that contains detailed information about the area where the user clicked, or the somewhat simpler [`TreeView.GetNodeAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yxbz43s.aspx) method, which will simply return `null` if no node exists at the location of the click.

Alternatively, to get the currently selected node at any time, you can just query the [`TreeView.SelectedNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx) property. If no node is selected, this will also return `null`.

Comment: My problem the `AfterSelect()` is not working while I Click many times on the node. when I use `MouseClick()` event the selectedNode is sometimes different

Comment: @Jiss When you click multiple times on the same node, you're not selecting a new node so there's no reason to raise `AfterSelect`. It's already selected. The behavior you're describing is relatively unusual. It's very rare that you would want some action to execute each time a node is clicked, even if it's already selected. Perhaps you should consider using checkboxes instead?

Comment: Just Imagine, I clicked once on a node.. then the event is fired. I wrote a program to show a form while clicking on the node. once the form is appeared i closed the form. If I want to reopen the form. I again clicked on the node. But the `AfterSelect()` will not work. the result is the form is not show

Comment: Then you should be able to handle the `Click` event and use the `SelectedNode` property.

Comment: event will show the oldest selected , not the immediate selected one.

Answer (score 8):

It would be better to use `treeView1_AfterSelect()` event because that gives the correct selected node text. The `treeView1_Click()` event will show the oldest selected not, not the immediate selected one.

You can achieve the selected node text on `Click` event

```
 private void treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
 }
```

Remember, the difference between `Click()` and `AfterSelect()` event is their eventargs

```
treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
```

**EDIT:**
Try out this on `Click()` event, I am sure this will help you.

```
 private void treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   TreeViewHitTestInfo info = treeView1.HitTest(treeView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
   if (info != null)
     MessageBox.Show(info.Node.Text);
 }
```

Comment: I believe your problem is, if a node is already selected and your click on it again you should get the text node. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way which works for me, it took me a while to get to do I wanted but it works.

```
Private Sub toolStripButton7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton7.Click

          Dim node As TreeNode = treeView1.SelectedNode
          Dim strRootPath As String = My.Settings.DefaultRootPath

          Dim strNode As String = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text

          Call treeViewRoot(strRootPath)

          Dim nodes As TreeNode() = treeView1.Nodes.Find(strRootPath & "\" & strNode, True)

          For Each node In nodes

                 treeView1.Focus()
                 treeView1.SelectedNode = node

          Next
End Sub
```